# Javascript : How to retrieve initial value after permutation

Tags: javascript, permutation

Starting with a 6-digits value (i.e "123456") and a [0->9] table, this script (but many other exist...) procuces the 123456th permutation of the table :

```
  let tabl10 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
      permut = permutation( 123456 , tabl10 )

  console.log(permut) // 0,4,1,6,5,9,2,3,7,8

  function permutation(n,a) {
      let f, k = [], l = a.length;
      a = a.slice();
      while (l--) {
         f = factorial(l);
         k.push(Math.floor(n / f));
         n %= f;
      }
      return k.map(function (i) {
         return a.splice(i, 1)[0];
      });
   }

   function factorial(n) {
       let r = 1;
       while (n) {
           r *= n;
           n--;
       }
       return r;
   }
```

My question is : is it possible to retrieve "123456" from the "0,4,1,6,5,9,2,3,7,8" permutation ?

We have 10! (3.6288 million) of possibles permutations and trying all of them one by one till we find the 123456th is painfull: it is possible to explore all permutations and retrieve the nth with a 7-digits table [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]: 7!=5040, but a 8-digits (40320) or higher definively freezes browsers. How to achieve this ?

Comment: So, you want to retrieve which permutation of  `0416592378` is `0123456`?

Comment: yes... I got the value `0416592378` which is the 123456th permut of table [0->9]. How to retrieve 123456 from the given value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) for a permutation `perm`, the i-th number is the number of the elements on the right of `i` that are less than `perm[i]`. So, given a permutation, you can compute its LC first, and then convert the LC from the factorial system to an int, which gives you the index of the permutation.

Complete code:

```js
// int => LC
function int2lc(n, len) {
    let lc = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        lc[len - i] = (n % i)
        n = (n / i) | 0
    }
    return lc
}

// LC => int
function lc2int(lc, len) {
    let n = 0, f = 1
    for (let i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        n += lc[len - i] * f
        f *= i
    }
    return n
}

// LC => permutation
function lc2perm(a, lc) {
    let perm = [], copy = [...a]
    for (let i = 0; i < lc.length; i++) {
        perm[i] = copy[lc[i]]
        copy.splice(lc[i], 1)
    }
    return perm
}

// permutation => LC
function perm2lc(perm) {
    let lc = []
    for (let i = 0; i < perm.length; i++) {
        let c = 0
        for (let k = i + 1; k < perm.length; k++)
            c += perm[k] < perm[i]
        lc[i] = c
    }
    return lc
}

//

A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

// index to perm

N = 123456
lc = int2lc(N, A.length)
console.log('LEHMER', ...lc)
perm = lc2perm(A, lc)
console.log('PERMUT', ...perm)

// perm to index

lc2 = perm2lc(perm)
console.log('LEHMER', ...lc2)
M = lc2int(lc2, A.length)
console.log('INDEX ', M)
```

Comment: @Wolden: you're welcome, it was fun. Learned something new today ;)

Comment: me too :-) works perfectly, great solution.